# Display of image changes on animated view change

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller loading with a nib that is behaving oddly. When loaded as the rootViewController like:

```
  self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

everything displays fine. Everything also displays fine when I use:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

to navigate to my view from another controller. However, when I use:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

A single image width is enlarged almost four times it's given width. Anyone know why an animation would cause my view to display differently as opposed to no animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with constraints. I can't speak to why the constraint only updated when the page animated, but once the constraints were corrected, the image became normal sized again.